# LSH and minhasing - Why does hashing the signature matrix make sense?

Tags: algorithm, hash, computer-science, similarity, lsh

I'm [learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-locality-sensitive-hashing-49f6d1f6134) about LSH and minhashing and I'm trying to understand the rational of hashing the signature matrix:

We divide the signature matrix to bands and we hash (using which hash function?) every portion of column to `k` buckets. Why would it make sense? If we use a regular hash function then even a slight difference in two columns would probably lead to different buckets.

I do understand the relation between the signature matrix to Jacard distance but I don't understand the next step which is essentially hashing that distributes items evenly.

Comment: Honestly that's the most confusing explanation of LSH I've ever seen.